# Expected value of distance between independent Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose $\{W^{(1)}_t, t\geq 0\}$ and {$W^{(2)}_t, t\geq 0\}$ are two independent Brownian motions. If I recall correctly, the distance between the two at a given time has the following property:

> $$\mathbb{E}\big|W^{(1)}_s-W^{(2)}_s\big|=\sqrt{s}$$

I'm having a hard time finding this in a book, but I'm pretty sure it's right. Can you explain why or tell me why I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the process
$$X_s = W^{(1)}_s-W^{(2)}_s$$
At any given time, this is the difference of two mean zero, independent, normals with variance $s$.  That means $X_s$ is a mean zero normal with variance $2s$.

So the question is, what is the expected value of the absolute value of a normal random variable.  This is called a [Folded Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution).  One that was folded from a normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma$ has mean
$$\sigma \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$
So in your case,
$$\sqrt{2s}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} = 2 \sqrt{\frac{s}{\pi}}$$

Comment: @eeeeeeeeee Happy to help.